# awk to provide extra space?

Tags: linux, unix

can some one please tell me, how can I write a awk program to provide extra space at the end of a line if required. So that the line length is maintained at 127 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `%-127s` format specifier pads a string to 127 characters:

```
awk '{printf "%-127s\n", $0}'
```

You could also do this in straight bash:

```
while read LINE; do printf "%-127s\n" "$LINE"; done
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your nice explanation. That clear things out a lot. Thank you.